# Caching large amounts of data

Tags: asp.net, caching, redis

I have been reading that lots of people use Redis or another key-value store/NoSQL solution as a distributed cache for their website.

Maybe I'm not understanding completely, but it seems a solution like this only works for shared data.  For example, if I have a website that requires a user to log-in and the queries they generate return data specific to only that user (in my case, banking/asset information) that can't be cached for all users, this type of solution doesn't work.

Unfortunately, the database is shared across all our applications and when it get bogged down, the website gets bogged down as well.  Since each user has gigabytes of information, I obviously can't cache all of that and each web page queries completely different information.

Is there some caching strategy that I can employ for this type of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A distributed cache like Velocity doesn't require that the data it stores be limited to "shared" data. But you do have to read the data from your DB and store it in the cache, which takes time.

A few alternatives:

- Partition your data, so it's spread out among several DB servers
- Add as much RAM as you can to each DB server, to allow SQL Server to cache what it can

There are many variations to the partitioning theme....

Is your web app load balanced? There are caching options at the web tier as well -- the ASP.NET object cache is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your web clients are requesting the same data more than once (for a given user).  So caching could give a benefit in that case.

But before you go implementing a huge caching solution, you really need to look at the queries that are particularly slow or executed a huge number of times and see if you can optimize them in any way.

Then look at upgrading your DB machine.

Answer (score 0):

I read a nice article about the performance issues that MySpace had when they had a huge growth.

You can find the article [here](http://www.baselinemag.com/c/a/Projects-Networks-and-Storage/Inside-MySpacecom/).

One quote from the article that stands out:

> The addition of the cache servers is "something we should have done
>   from the beginning, but we were growing too fast and didn't have time
>   to sit down and do it," Benedetto adds

If the problem is in your database server think about partitioning your data and making use of a database farm to spread the load. Also think about SSD's! They can really speed up your database access code.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how dynamic your data is you could consider using [Fragment Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h30h475z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). This will cache the HTML of the page rather than the data so if the volume of data is prohibtive to cache then this might work for you